# Client-server application between two computers in the same network (using boost::asio)

Tags: c++, connection, client-server, boost-asio, lan

I'm trying to set up a basic communication between my desktop PC and my laptop (latter one using wireless connection) both being in the same network, using the boost::asio tutorials: [synchronous client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1/src.html) and [synchronous server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2/src.html) (in c++).

When I run both the server and client on the same machine (using the localhost and the datetime port as parameters), it works splendidly. But if I try to set up the laptop as server (tested it with `netstat -anb` from the command prompt, it is indeed running and listening to port 13 as it's supposed to, and I even deactivated the firewall to make sure it doesn't cause any problems), I cannot connect to it with the client (set up on the PC), no matter what IP I tried (localhost, and basically any IPs that `ipconfig -all` gave me).

So no matter what I tried, I cannot find the correct address that which the client can use to connect to the server.
Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Can we see the `netstat` output that convinced you the server was listening? If you didn't pick one IP address to make work, it's not surprising that none work.

Comment: Sure: http://i40.tinypic.com/am382a.png

Indeed I didn't specify any IP addresses in the server, though I tried to do so afterwards with many IPs (mostly what ipconfig gave me, and setting the same IP in the client as well of course), without any improvements.

Comment: It worked fine between two computers in my workplace (so now I know that the IP I have to give to the client is the server's machine's local IP), so the problem is in my home network. Will look into this, thank you very much for responding! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely your home network, not your program.

Assuming both your PC and your laptop are both connected to the same router (PC via ethernet and laptop via wireless), any traffic generated by either machine is being sent to the router first. When the this traffic gets to the router, it's most likely doing network address translation ([NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)), and then sending the traffic into the internet. If this is the case, the requests from your client may be getting sent into the larger internet (where the internal IP address you're sending requests to is not found / not running the service you expect on the given port), rather than being forwarded to the server running in your local network.

To test this hypothesis, run a [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) from the client using the IP address / port number the server is running on. If the route goes through more than 3 hops ( intern client -> router -> internal server ), it's getting sent into the larger internet. If this is the case, you may be able to configure your router ( maybe look into [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) ) such that any traffic with a given IP / port gets forwarded to the internal server, rather than into the larger internet.

Comment: You are right, I tried to run the applications between two computers at my workplace, it worked like a charm. So the problem is in my home network, I'll look into port forwarding. Many thanks! :)